# Slack 4.9.1 not launching in 20.04 LTS

Tags: slack

Despite installing it many a times, slack doesn't start upon launching it. tried many ways but no luck! please help!

Comment: Too vague. You will need to add details. Error notices, crash log or notes in the various log files that explain what is wrong for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Hey Murali Kanakala! [Please make sure that your question shows as much information about your problem as possible. The more work and time you put on your question, the easier, faster and better the answers will be. Also remember that we can only help you using the information you have provided on the question. If your question lacks information, a solution will take more time to arrive.](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is uninstalling all packages, clearing snap files and installing again:

```
sudo apt remove slack
sudo snap remove slack
sudo dpkg -P slack-desktop
rm -rf ~/snap/slack/
rm -rf .config/autostart/slack.desktop

sudo snap install slack
```